# Comparing the font size and style of two strings using java

Tags: string, fonts

Let's say I have a String object1 "Hello World";.
I also have another String object2 "Hello World"; but the second object has a font size of 15 and normal style compared to the first object which has a font size of 12 but it's **bolded**. How can I compare the two strings and see which object has a bigger font size.

Comment: please be more precise: Java `String` objects have no fonts or font size or anything of that nature, they're just String primitives, so what do you *really* have? Do you mean you have pixels on a JPanel or something, drawn using awt/swing draw methods etc? Remember to read through the [how to as a question](/help/how-to-ask) document and update your question accordingly

Comment: I have a .txt file that contains the words "Hello World". I also have another .txt file that contains the same words but in a bigger font size. I want to read these files and store them into an array list. After doing that, I want to compare the sizes of the words in the array with regards to their font. This is my first post so I am not sure if I am making sense.

Comment: no you don't, `.txt` files don't have font information, they're plain string data files without any markup or metadata.

Comment: ok thank you. I will work on what I am trying to say and I will ask again once I have a clear understanding of my goal.